# Who changed my matrix? Mysterious bug

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have been stuck on this small bug for the past two hours and now I am desperate. Any help is highly appreciated!

The algorithm is for making the matrix for the `Longest Common Subsequence` between two sequences problem. And the matrix is used as a reference table in the [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach. Pasting the related code

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  vector<int> A, B;
  A.push_back(0);
  A.push_back(15);
  A.push_back(20);
  B.push_back(0);
  B.push_back(20);
  B.push_back(15);

  int a = 2;
  int b = 2;
  int matrix[a][b];
  memset(matrix, 0, sizeof(int)*a*b);

  for (int i = 0; i <= a; ++i)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j <= b; ++j)
    {
      if (i == 0 || j == 0)
      {
        matrix[i][j] = 0;
      } else 
      {
        if (A[i] == B[j])
        {
          matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
          printf("matrix at row %i column %i: %i\n", i, j, matrix[i][j]);
        } else
        {
          matrix[i][j] = max(matrix[i - 1][j], matrix[i][j - 1]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  printf("matrix at row 1 column 2: %i\n", matrix[1][2]);
  printf("matrix at row 2 column 1: %i\n", matrix[2][1]);
}
```

If I compile and run it with

```
g++ -Wall soquestion1.cpp -o soquestion1
./soquestion1
```

I get

```
matrix at row 1 column 2: 1
matrix at row 2 column 1: 1
matrix at row 1 column 2: 0     #WTHHHHHH, who changed my matrix!?
matrix at row 2 column 1: 1
```

Thanks for reading that far.

Comment: offhandguess, one of the lines where you're re-writing the matrix: `matrix[i][j] = ....` ... in other words, YOU'RE changing the matrix.

Comment: You're accessing a 2x2 matrix with indexes outside 0..1. Its **undefined behavior**. Ex: The end of your matrix is at `matrix[1][1]`, so what did you expect to get back from `matrix[1][2]` in your first `printf()` ?

Comment: Moreover, you define an array with dimensions known at runtime (`a` and `b` are not const). VLAs are not (yet) part of the C++ std. Probably this compiles due to a GCC extension (and it should warn that IIRC)

Comment: @WhozCraig Nice! You saved my day/life!

Comment: @sbabbi What's problem with that?

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= a; ++i)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j <= b; ++j)
    {
```

Here's your problem. You go out of bounds, resulting in... "something".

Make it `<a` and `<b`, and you should be fine. Also you are accessing the matrix itself, didn't really read through what that does there.
Have you done a check on what the result SHOULD be?

```
  printf("matrix at row 1 column 2: %i\n", matrix[1][2]);
  printf("matrix at row 2 column 1: %i\n", matrix[2][1]);
```

It should be `matrix[0][1]` and `matrix[1][0]`

Note: the expected result should be 0 and 0

Comment: I deliberately did that. The problem was, I didn't initialise the matrix correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is kind of a mess. I cleaned it up some.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
  int A[] = { 0, 15, 20 };
  int B[] = { 0, 20, 15 };

  const size_t MatrixDim = 3;
  int matrix[MatrixDim][MatrixDim] = { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } }; 
  // or memset(matrix, 0, sizeof(matrix));

  // only operate on dimensions 1 and 2, leave 0,j and i,0 elements as 0. 
  for (size_t i = 1; i < MatrixDim; ++i)
  {
    for (size_t j = 1; j < MatrixDim; ++j)
    {
      if (A[i] == B[j])
      {
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
        printf("a. matrix at row %i column %i: %i\n", i, j, matrix[i][j]);
      }
      else
      {
        matrix[i][j] = std::max(matrix[i - 1][j], matrix[i][j - 1]);
        printf("b. matrix at row %i column %i: %i\n", i, j, matrix[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < MatrixDim; ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < MatrixDim; ++j) {
      printf("%02d ", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/vGk4oB

Output:

```
a. matrix at row 1 column 2: 1
a. matrix at row 2 column 1: 1
b. matrix at row 2 column 2: 1
00 00 00 
00 00 01 
00 01 01
```